# My object have weird lines

Tags: objects

Check my hat.

[image]

[image]

What can I do?

===>> **Blender files:** [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dm6fegct7hpdh4h/MagePlayer3.blend?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u83n0ukf22yuwpn/MagePlayer3.blend1?dl=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some faces of your hat mesh are badly oriented. Select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>